# java List extends abstract

Tags: java, list, abstract, extends

I have a

```
public abstract class Person{/*..*/}

public class Woman extends Person{/*..*/}
public class Man extends Person{/*..*/}
```

I'm trying to instantiate a List that could contain either Man or Woman, I tried this :

```
List<? extends Person> PersonTypes = new List<? extends Person>()
```

But it can't be instantiated, is there a way to achieve what I want and keeping Person abstract ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List is an Interface and thus cannot be instantiated itself, similar to your abstract Person class which cannot be instantiated either.

You should instantiate a class which implements List, such as ArrayList:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Comment: Ok thanks, i should have think about that, what stupid mistake I made. Thx it works now

Answer (score 2):

It should work.

```
List<Person> PersonTypes = new ArrayList<Person>()
```

Answer (score 0):

The List is also an interface and cannot be instantiated.  Try this:

```
List<? extends Person> PersonTypes = new ArrayList<Person>();
```

Comment: This won't compile. You can't instantiate a wildcard parameterized type.